# Do I need to convert booleans to ints to enter them in a machine learning algorithm?

Tags: machine-learning, python, pandas

My dataset contains a lot of columns with booleans do I really need to change them so I can insert them into the algorithm?

I'm gonna use KNN right now but will test other algorithms later so I'm trying to ready up my dataset

Comment: KNN requires a distance metric. What is the distance between TRUE and FALSE?

Comment: How can I find this out? I'm a complete noob and this is my first project on data science

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Python, `True` and `False` are *cast* implicitly into integers:

```
True == 1     # True!
False == 0    # True!
```

Although they are not the same objects - you can test this with `True is 1`, which returns `False`.

This means that an algorithm running in pure Python should work without conversion. Many libraries/algorithms have some part implemented in C/C++ in the background, in which case you might run into problems.

You could try the model on your Pandas DataFrame as boolean. If it crashes, you know you must convert to integers/floats.

Even if it doesn't crash, you could convert the values to integers or floats and run it for comparison. Here is a short example:

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd                                                                               
In [2]: df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[0, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'b':[True, False, True, False, False]})
In [3]: df                                                                                                
Out[3]: 
   a      b
0  0   True
1  2  False
2  3   True
3  4  False
4  5  False
```

Convert everything to boolean

```
In [4]: df.astype(bool)                                                                                   
Out[4]: 
      a      b
0  False   True
1  True   False
2  True    True
3  True   False
4  True   False

In [5]: df.astype(float)                                                                                  
Out[5]: 
     a    b
0  0.0  1.0
1  2.0  0.0
2  3.0  1.0
3  4.0  0.0
4  5.0  0.0
```

Comment: I see you used float and not int is that intentional and its preferred over int ?

Comment: @dungeon - for two reasons: (1) to show you can convert a dataframe to any type (with some constraints) and (2) so you could put that in a model and see that floats will likely work as well as integers.